# Why doesn't my for-loop work as i want it to work?

Tags: python, for-loop

```
import random

def calculate_score():
    worplist = [1, 1, 5]
    for worp in worplist:
        if worp == 1:
            worplist.remove(worp)
        if worp == 6:
            worplist.append(worp)
    
    

    print(sum(worplist))
calculate_score()
```

I want every 1 to be removed but it only removes the first one. Then if I add a 6 to the list it doesn't work at all. Any help?

Comment: `worp == 6` is never true

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an "else if" instead of another "if" statement?

```py
import random

def calculate_score():
    worplist = [1, 1, 5]
    for worp in worplist:
        if worp == 1:
            worplist.remove(worp)
        elif worp == 6:
            worplist.remove(worp)
    print(sum(worplist))

calculate_score()
```

Comment: Yes, but if I add a 6 to the list it will still give no output.

Comment: It gives me 6 as the output, I'm not sure what the matter is with your code.